# add data belongs to filtered columns in excel and update the data

Tags: filter, pivot-table

How can I add data belongs to filtered columns in excel (using pivot table or filter function) and get update when change base data for new month? Filtered data will refresh but data which I added beside filtered columns does not go down and remain at the first row. Moreover, I could not make a table from the filtered data and added data beside them or add to data model and make relationship.

There is no problem with my base data which are updated each month. But every month in base data, we will assign each rows to one person to analyze and I have used "Filter function" to show assigned data to each person in different sheet names. For analyzing, they need to add columns to filtered data, such as data validation filling, comment,... and I need to relate theses added columns to filtered array. So every month I will not have problem with updated data and I can upload the analyzed data to Power BI. Would you please help me to understand the right way of doing this.

Best Regards